# Unable to saveAsTextFile in spark but able to read the output

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, save

I am quite new with python and spark and I have an issue that require your help. Before that, I have four different dataset and using the same code for all these dataset, two of them were able to saveAsTextFile, the other two is not. The code i try to run is a sentiment analysis, and when I print out the output, it is readable. However, when i try to saveAsTextFile, there's an error for the other two dataset.
Appreciate if anyone can try to figure out what is wrong with my code as below:

```
def main():

   data = sc.textFile("filename.csv").map(lambda x:x.split(",")).filter(lambda x:len(x) == 10).filter(lambda x:len(x[1]) > 0).map(lambda x:str(x).replace("'","")).map(lambda x:str(x).replace('"',''))
   data1 = data.map(lambda x:x[1]).map(lambda x:remove_features(x)).map(lambda x:abb_en(x)).map(lambda x:TextBlob(x).sentiment.polarity).map(lambda x:polarity(x))

   data_save=data.zip(data1)
   print(data_save.take(5))
   data_save.saveAsTextFile("filename_1")'


if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Configure your Spark environment
   conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("My Spark_1 Application")
   sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf = conf)

   main()

   sc.stop()
```

The error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1418.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1090)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1088)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1061)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:964)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1552)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1552)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1538)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, 9LVT2H2.mh.corp.net, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitTask(OutputCommitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:129)
    ... 9 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2169)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitTask(OutputCommitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:129)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the exception, it appeared that the code is executed in Windows environment.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
```

Not sure what is the file path specified. Please check if following things are in place

```
1. winutil.exe and hadoop.dll
2. add to $HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Also, check the file location which you have specified having write access if it is a local file. In general it should not cause any issue if Hadoop path is set and file write access is given.

Comment: Hi Roy, thank you for the feedback. Both winutils.exe and hadoop.dll are in HADOOP_HOME/bin directory yet the error is still persists